# Automatically create image file from text and default image in PHP or JS?

Tags: javascript, php, image

I've got a site where users can enter text up to 250 characters. I want to lay this text over a default image and output a new image file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a new image.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreate.php

Then merge the two together imagecopymerge()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php